# Symfony2 auto-triggered tasks

Tags: symfony, triggers, cron

I want to notify a user when one of his entities expires. I added an "expires_in" datetime attribute that represents a countdown.

I don't think a cron task launched every second is a good/workable solution to update the countdown for this entity and trigger the event...

I am searching for an automated way to tell symfony when one attribute has reached a certain value, for all the instances of this entity.

Is there any other viable solution to this problem ?

Comment: The viable solution would be run a cron. A more advanced solution would be to send a message to a message queue (e.g. RabbitMQ) and have a consumer that would send an email when it finds a message with an expired value. If the message is not expired it could just `nack` it (i.e. not acknowledge it) sending it back into the queue to check again later.

Comment: I think I will try with the console commands, it seems to work like a cron task but triggered by symfony ! Thank you for your answer

Comment: That is certainly the simplest and totally viable solution. In fact I think you will find you will begin to write most of your cron and command line operations with the console command. We certainly do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions.

1. Try to check reached entities every http request or 1 of N requests. So you should create event listener ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html))
2. You can create php daemon, that check entities every N minutes. Use for it Symfony2 command ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html))